# TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**This is my Main.js file**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const editByID = (id) =>{
    axios.post('http://localhost:8000/getbyID',{
            id:id
        })
        .then(({data}) => {
            if(data.success == 1){
                alert(data.msg);  
                let tmpArr = [];
                for( var i = 0 ; i < data.user.length ; i++ ){
                    tmpArr.push(data.user[i])
                }
                // uid = data.user[0].id;
                return tmpArr
                // console.log(data.user[0].id);
                // editUser(uid);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}   //editByID

export default HomePage;
export {getData,editByID};
```

**This is my FormUpdate.js file**

```
    componentDidMount(){
        this.getAllByID();
    }

    getAllByID = () =>{
        editByID().then(tmpArr=>{            
            this.setState({
                items:tmpArr                
            },
            ()=>{
                console.log(this.state);
            })
        })
    }   //getAllByID
```

in FormUpdate.js tmpArr is not getting as an array. But why? It show the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
FormUpdate.getAllByID
F:/react/react-crud/src/components/FormUpdate.js:21
  18 | 
  19 |    getAllByID = () =>{
  20 |        console.log(this.props.location.id);
> 21 |        editByID(this.props.location.id).then(tmpArr=>{
     | ^  22 |            
  23 |            this.setState({
  24 |                items:tmpArr
```

What I'm doing wrong? when I'm doing console.log(tmpArr) from Main.js it shows result perfectly.

Comment: add return to your axios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`editById` doesnt return anything. Add the `return` keyword:

```
const editByID = (id) => {
    return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/getbyID',{ // Add return here
            id:id
        })

...(rest of code)...
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning a promise in your editById. Try this

```
const editByID = (id) =>{
    return axios.post('http://localhost:8000/getbyID',{
            id:id
        })
        .then(({data}) => {
            if(data.success == 1){
                alert(data.msg);  
                let tmpArr = [];
                for( var i = 0 ; i < data.user.length ; i++ ){
                    tmpArr.push(data.user[i])
                }
                // uid = data.user[0].id;
                return tmpArr
                // console.log(data.user[0].id);
                // editUser(uid);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Rashomon's suggestion, you could just use an Object Literal Syntax by wrapping it in **parentheses** instead of **curly brackets**.

```js
const editByID = (id) => (
        axios.post('http://localhost:8000/getbyID',{
            id:id
        })
        .then(({data}) => {
            if(data.success == 1){
                alert(data.msg);  
                let tmpArr = [];
                for( var i = 0 ; i < data.user.length ; i++ ){
                    tmpArr.push(data.user[i])
                }
                // uid = data.user[0].id;
                return tmpArr
                // console.log(data.user[0].id);
                // editUser(uid);
            }
            else{
                alert(data.msg);
            }

        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    );
```